# AMOR desktop pet thingy

Tags: games

i loved this old app from older version of ubuntu

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/amor-a-creature-for-your-desktop.html

Anyone know how to get the same app on ubuntu 20.04

Thanks a million...

Comment: Sorry, not gonna happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still possible, as the project is really [alive](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdetoys/amor).

But you need to compile it by yourself by executing the following commands on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git cmake extra-cmake-modules extra-cmake-modules libqt5x11extras5-dev libkf5doctools-dev libkf5dbusaddons-dev libkf5coreaddons-dev libkf5i18n-dev libkf5config-dev libkf5windowsystem-dev libkf5xmlgui-dev

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://invent.kde.org/games/amor.git
cd amor
git reset --hard 013e1f4d5e2207fda5eec111b5bedeee9adba785
cmake .
make -j$(nproc)
sudo make install
```

and then run it using `amor` or from menu by AMOR icon.

Comment: Thanks a million... it works like a charm...!